# Xpages - SSJS code via custom control property

Tags: xpages, custom-controls, xpages-ssjs

Is it possible to define some SSJS via property definition on a custom control?

For example, to test, I have a property definition on a custom control called onClickCode. Within said custom control, I have a radio button, and in the onClick/onChange event I try to write compositeData.onClickCode. This seems to execute when the page loads, rather than on the the onClick event.

Code that passes in property definitions is:

```
<xc:ccQuestionInterimRadiosYesNo required="true"
                        dataSource="#{document1}" fieldName="Q1"
                        helpText="Please select an answer"
                        placeholder="Enter any further details here..."
                        questionHeader="primary" questionTextNJD="QuestionTextNJD">
                        <xc:this.radioOptions><![CDATA[#{javascript:return ['Yes', 'No'];}]]></xc:this.radioOptions>
                        <xc:this.questionText><![CDATA[${javascript:"Ready for section 2?"}]]></xc:this.questionText>
                        <xc:this.onClickCode><![CDATA[#{javascript:'print("Hello")'}]]></xc:this.onClickCode>
                    </xc:ccQuestionInterimRadiosYesNo>
```

Code on the radio button within said custom control is:

```
<!-- RADIO BUTTON GROUP -->
                        <xp:radioGroup
                            loaded="${!empty compositeData.placeholder}"
                            value="#{compositeData.dataSource[compositeData.fieldName]}"
                            required="${compositeData.required}" layout="lineDirection">

                            <xp:this.validators>
                                <xp:validateRequired
                                    message="#{javascript:compositeData.helpText}">
                                </xp:validateRequired>
                            </xp:this.validators>

                            <xp:this.id><![CDATA[${javascript:"radioGroup"+compositeData.fieldName}]]></xp:this.id>
                            <xp:selectItems>
                                <xp:this.value><![CDATA[#{javascript:compositeData.radioOptions}]]></xp:this.value>
                            </xp:selectItems>
                            <xp:eventHandler event="onchange"
                                submit="true" refreshMode="complete">
                                <xp:this.action><![CDATA[#{javascript:compositeData.onClickCode}]]></xp:this.action>
                            </xp:eventHandler></xp:radioGroup>
```

**UPDATE:**

Custom control on a page passes:

```
onClickCode="#{javascript:test1}"
```

Code on the onChange event of a radio button within the custom control:

```
if (compositeData.onClickCode) {
    compositeData.onClickCode.call();
}
```

Script containing the code is part of my theme:

```
<script src="/StdServerScripts.jss" clientSide="false"></script>
```

Code within said script is:

```
function test1() {
    print("Hello");
}
```

Comment: I do something similar where I pass in a SSJS method. In the custom control I then use call() to execute the passed in method (compositeData.functionName.call()). The property "functionName" is of type javax.faces.el.MethodBinding. Maybe this can lead you in the right direction?

Comment: Hi Per, that definitely gives me something to work with. I was thinking in future I may also want to try and compute the refreshID for a partial refresh, which is easy enough, but whilst you're here, have you tried computing between a full and partial refresh? For example, in the source code something like refreshMode="compsiteData.refreshMode"? Or would it be easier to create 2 custom controls? One for full refreshes and one for full?

In the meantime, I'll try creating a method tomorrow and let you know how I get on, thanks.

Comment: @ChrisRichards both `refreshId` and `refreshMode` properties of `eventHandler` component support ValueBinding expressions, so this should work

Comment: http://notesspeak.blogspot.com/2013/05/passing-ssjs-function-as-custom.html

Comment: @PerHenrikLausten - When I try to set my custom property to choose my function, I get the little "Add" icon, but clicking it says no items found? I include the SSJS script lib containing the function in my application via a theme.... UPDATE: Just read the link from Frantisek and set the editor to "Method Binding Editor" to resolve this. Thanks

Comment: I now get test1 not found, where test1 is my function. The function is included in a script library that is included on every page via a theme so I'm not sure why it can't find it? I've done a full clean and build of the project.....

Comment: @ChrisRichards can you add your code to the question?

Comment: @PerHenrikLausten have just done so, thanks - It looks like my function is not being loaded...When I look at the scripts when debugging, my new function doesn't seem to be there.... I've tried cleaning and building multiple times

Comment: I have added a print statement at the start of the onChange event, and even the print statement does not get executed, however the partial refresh does occur..... try{
 print("1");
 if (compositeData.onClickCode) {
  compositeData.onClickCode.call();
 }

 print("2");
}catch(e){
 openLogBean.addError(e,this.getParent());
}